# How do I edit after squashing while doing an interactive rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I can't figure out how to get access to the results of a squashed commit during a rebase.  I would like to be able to edit the commit after 2 commits have been squashed into the previous one.  My rebase file looks like this:

```
p f70f90f ... some message ...
s 514ee77 ... some message ...
s ab01b05 ... some message ...
                                <-- want to edit 3 commits here!
p b109cc1 ... some message ...
```

I have already tried:

```
e f70f90f ... some message ...
s 514ee77 ... some message ...
s ab01b05 ... some message ...
p b109cc1 ... some message ...
```

But that lets me edit the first commit, then squashes the next two.

And:

```
p f70f90f ... some message ...
s 514ee77 ... some message ...
s ab01b05 ... some message ...
p b109cc1 ... some message ...
```

But that takes me straight into my text editor to edit the commit message for the last 3 commits, without giving me a chance to edit the commit itself.

I believe I could solve this issue using two rebases: 1) in which I squash, and 2) in which I edit.  But the branch has a sufficient number of following commits that rebasing takes quite a while.

How do I do this in a single rebase?  Or is there another, more appropriate solution?

*(I am aware of the issues with rebasing publicly visible work, those aren't problems for this project).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stop for editing on the third commit

```
p f70f90f ... some message ...
s 514ee77 ... some message ...
e ab01b05 ... some message ...
p b109cc1 ... some message ...
```

that way you stop at `ab01b05` for editing. So if you

`git reset --soft HEAD^`

you can then do your changes. Then

`git commit --amend`

will squash the changes to the last commit (which now is the squash of `f70f90f` and `514ee77`)

and you are set.

After that a

`git rebase --continue`

will take you to the next step of your rebase.

Comment: @MattFenwick: it *does* work, but you may want to save the third commit's commit-text before you do the `git reset --soft HEAD^`: `cp .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG /tmp/save; git reset --soft HEAD^`

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out, but it works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @torek you are right, I didn't thought of that.
There is another way to perform this but it is quite an ugly hack

`p 123456 ...`
`s 234567 ...`
`s 345678 ...`
`e`
`p 456789 ...`

will stop for that point for editing but with an error!

Comment: Or simply `git checkout -b reb` then _refresh gitk_ then `git reset --soft HEAD^` - much much better, get into that habit