# Mistakably added large files to git, willing to skip that commit upon next push, possible?

Tags: git

I have added a directory which contained several large files (100's of gigabytes).
I then ran:

```
git rm --cached large-files-list
```

However, I now several commits later, willing to push changes to server, but wonder if it can be done without pushing that specific commit. Pushing this commit with nearly half terabytes of data is not going to please anyone.

Not sure if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do an [interactive-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

lets say you have

```
C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4
```

where C1 is the start of your branch, C2 is the buggy commit and C4 is your last commit.

I would suggest doing an interactive rebase where you'll stop for edit after C2, and discard the addition of the large files. If C2 contains only that, you can just remove the relevant line in the interactive rebase prompted editor.

After that you would be able to push your changes without having these files in history at all.

for details on this interactive rebase issue you can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130419/687142 that might suit your case.